# Mongoose - How to update a MongoDB document field which initially stores a list of strings, to store a list of objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an old Mongo database from an old project (with Mongoose used to communicate with the DB). There, I have a document structure which stores `fruitsInBasket` as a list of Strings.
Old Structure (Basket):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const basketSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: [true, 'Please provide valid user'],
    },
    fruitsInBasket: {
        type: [String],
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Basket', basketSchema);
```

In the new structure, we have a collection of fruits. So, only a reference to that fruit can be stored in the above Basket collection documents.
New Basket Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const basketSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: [true, 'Please provide valid user'],
    },
    fruitsInBasket: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Fruit',
        }
    ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Basket', basketSchema);
```

So, this structure works perfectly for newly created entries. However, while fetching the old data, the response does not contain the `fruitsInBasket` attribute at all. The values are still shown in the database (Mongo Compass) as strings, but are not fetched.

I tried to fetch the existing fruits list for each user in the Basket collection, then creating a list of the fruit IDs from the Fruit collection based on fruits fetched and then updating the Basket collection document accordingly.
However, while executing the script, I could see that the field `fruitsInBasket` itself is not fetched by MongoDB. The response looked something like this:

```
{
user: new ObjectId("64f9f9c6511b3aa6ae325f90"),
__v: 3
}
```

How to update the existing documents in the collection to adhere to the new collection structure?

Comment: I suspect the field is being fetched, but Mongoose is dropping it because it does not conform to the schema.  If you change the schema to define fruitsInBasket as type [mixed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) does that field get returned?

Comment: My advice, which you are free to ignore, would be to create a new property `fruits: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Fruit' } ]` and do an `updateMany` or [update with aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to set the `fruits` array to the corresponding `ObjectId` of the fruit stored in the original `fruitsInBasket` array where those are strings. Then remove the `fruitsInBasket` array. This is best done on a test first of course and then outside patterns of business activity once you have your query nailed.

Comment: @Joe, looks like that is the culprit. Changing the field type to `mixed` works.

Comment: @jQueeny thanks for this approach! This looks doable and less time-consuming.